# How to save business card in illustrator to be used in photoshop as mockup?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, business, mockup

i have a problem here, trying to design a business card in illustrator and save it as eps to be used in photoshop to create mockup.

The thing is, there are bleed line, trim line and safe line. When I view the eps file in photoshop, the background extend until the bleed line. I just want it extends until trim line only because that would be the real size of the final printed product to put on mockup.

So, how should I save the illustrator file so that there's no bleed line included? Any help?

UPDATE: currently I'm creating a mask to hide the bleed area, is this the exact way of saving the ai file? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried all the different formats and options when doing a "save as" in Illustrator? Have you tried importing the EPS or AI or PDF in different manners in Photoshop using different options in the dialog boxes? How do you open/import your files? Etc. This is a very basic question and you'll probably find 10 different ways to fix your issue yourself faster than us trying to figure out how your crop marks are inserted in your original vector file and what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can save the file as PDF and import that into photoshop; [it should be able to recognize the different boxes](http://imgur.com/Us9ejCJ) i.e. trim, bleed and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

To go from Illustrator to Photoshop, just open your Illustrator document in Photoshop.

You don’t need to use EPS to go from Photoshop to Illustrator. They are both Adobe apps that not only understand each other’s proprietary formats, they also are part of the same PDF-based workflow. So if you did want to make an intermediary file, it should be PDF.

But I would recommend you just design the business card in Illustrator. There are many advantages to that.

[Should I design business cards in InDesign, Illustrator or Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/should-i-design-business-cards-in-indesign-illustrator-or-photoshop?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up the Illustrator file in Illustrator.
2. Select the artwork minus the marks you don't need.
3. Copy (cmd + c or ctrl + c).
4. Open up Photoshop.
5. Paste the copied artwork (cmd + v, ctrl + v) - Photoshop (since CS
   5 I believe) will ask if you'd like to make the pasted vector artwork a smart object - select yes.
6. Do whatever you need to do with the smart-object version of your
   business card in Photoshop