# Which software is best to create banner/billboard?

Tags: cs6, software-recommendation, signage

Which software is best to design a large banner/billboard? I know how to use Photoshop, Illustrator and InDesign CS6, but have never done a project with large designs. Which one is better to use for this project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to print an image at a certain size. What dimensions and resolution should I use?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-at-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolution-shoul)

Comment: I would otherwise not reply to this question, but the OP asks for software selection advise, rather than dimensions and resolution. The advice in the answer you link is valuable to jiru00255, of course, even though it does not appear to be software specific.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Any of these could be used.  "Best" is subjective. What kind of graphics does the banner contain?  For example, is it predominantly vector, or raster graphics?

Comment: This question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/should-i-design-business-cards-in-indesign-illustrator-or-photoshop/27624#27624 contains a lot of information with regards to the differences between InDesign, Illustrator and Photoshop, albeit in a different context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, it depends upon what kind of file your billboard company would ask for, I would strongly recommend illustrator as it is a vector graphic software leading your output to be of a good quality.
When you will try to work for such high-resolution files in photoshop it will load your file to be a .psb file that can be a very heavy file and you might face issues with such files, but If you are using images in the billboard designs then I would suggest you to edited the images in photoshop first on a larger scale and then import it to illustrator because an illustrator is a vector graphics software that works on points and the images contains pixels so for images photoshop is the best option and that way the quality of image would remain high.
I would strongly recommend Illustrator as it is the best for print media.
I would not suggest photoshop as when you will try to take a high-resolution file in photoshop for such large dimensions it will be converted to a PSB file and it will be a very large and heavy file making it hard to work with.
Also, when you will work for the same in illustrator the file would be less large and the quality of the vector would be better.

Answer (score 0):

will you be printing this banner/billboard? Your printer resource (person) would likely advise for you to use Illustrator, as the images created will scale nicely without aliasing or artifacts, when properly done.