# Auto sizing text to fit a box

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to create series of name labels using illustrator.
I've managed to use the variable xml from excel.
However, the long name is too long to fit into the label.
If I resize it, the short name will be too small (not filling the box/label).

Wondering if there is a way to fit the text to a box/shape?
For instance the short name will become bigger and the long name will become smaller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

InDesign is better for this, it uses the same XLS importing system and 100% superior in working with text. Yes, that includes automatic box size, width, height, and the way text flows and breaks. See this answer:

- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/27596/62949

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've seen indesign but never used it. My main concern would be the stroke that I normally export to printing RIP software as die cut line.
Not sure if indesign still support that kind of stuff.

Comment: Of course it does man :) Used die cuts myself in ID many times. https://indesignsecrets.com/making-a-die-cut-shape-in-indesign.php